# How to setup Google Analytics A/B testing feature using the Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I got instruction + a code snippets for setting A/B test via Google Analytics. 
Any pointers on how to best set it up using Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. Google Tag Manager doesn't support Experiments, so you'll need to go the old school way - hard-coding.